# Opposite of "client"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, antonyms

Is there an antonym of *client* for the following context?

> The [?] performs services for his clients.

Usually one would just specify the profession or job title:

> The contractor does home improvement for his clients.

But is there a term that is as generic as *client*? I thought of *professional*, but that obviously implies they are practicing a profession, which they might not be.

Comment: The the word you are looking for is the other half of a relationship, not an opposite. You want a *complement* (the part that *completes* the concept) not an *antonym*.

Comment: Server, of course :)

Comment: @AffableGeek In the US, *server* is usually reserved for wait-staff (waiters and waitresses) in restaurants and bars.

Comment: @bib I'm joking.  Just a silly little [IT-insider humor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model)

Comment: @AffableGeek Sorry. And in my rush to correct, I missed the obvious tech reference.

Comment: @bib Note that complementary relationships are still considered [a kind of antonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_(semantics)).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have pointed out some of the difficulties related to the broad range of possible categories of services involved. Lawyers have clients, as do carpenters, manicurists and numerous other professions and tradespeople.

A term that is sometimes used is ***[service provider](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/service-provider)***.

> BUSINESS a company that provides a service, for example insurance or medical treatment

It distinguishes the company or person proving services from a provider of goods (whose counterparts are usually called customers). Note, however, that the term is also used to identify a company that provides internet connectivity.

Comment: Some folks use _vendor_ in this context too.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider:

> **Consultant:** 2: one who gives professional advice or services : expert

from m-w.com

Answer (score 0):

I actually think "contractor", which you've mentioned yourself, is as close as you're likely to find to a generic complement for "client".  The nature of the relationship is that the client engages the "contractor" (i.e. the interaction is initiated by the client -- this is how the client-server terminology is derived), and enters into some kind of agreement.  Idiomatically, "contractor" will frequently sound odd in this context, but semantically it expresses the relationship in a suitably generic way, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

It is common to pair client with 'business' (the business provides services to its clients), but you seem to be asking about a certain individual rather than an entity.  'Businessman' works as well, but it is interesting that 'client' (or 'customer') can be so vague while the other side of the transaction seems to be specified more precisely.

Answer (score -3):

If one is not a client then they are in fact a prospect.

Edit- An advisor.

Comment: Please read the question carefully and **answer the question**, which was effectively asking for a name for *client of ???* - not a name for a prospective client.